# Non-local field redefinition and $S$-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, non-locality

It is known that for local field redefinitions for which the LSZ formula is valid:
$$\langle 0|\phi(x)|p\rangle \neq 0$$ field redefinitions don't change the S-matrix.
(See QMechanic's answer to [Equivalence Theorem of the S-Matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69828/equivalence-theorem-of-the-s-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1))

But is it true for non-local field redefintions? For instance if I take a field redefinition of the form: 
$$\psi(x)=e^{-l\Box} \phi(x)$$

Will the S-matrix be invariant under this?

From QMechanic's explanation linked above and the answer by AccidentalFourier Transform here it would seem that the answer should be yes.

Edit: My main concerns are

1. Is such a transformation invertible? Is this a concern?
2. Any boundary condition on $\psi$ would translate to infinitely many boundary conditions on $\phi$. Is this relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim 1.** If $\psi(x)$ is an *arbitrary* operator that satisfies
\begin{equation}
\langle 0|\psi(x)|p\rangle\neq 0\tag1
\end{equation}
then it is a valid interpolating field, and as such, it can be used in the LSZ formula. The **proof** can be found in any introductory text, such as Weinberg.

**Claim 2.** If we assume that
\begin{equation}
\langle 0|\phi(x)|p\rangle\neq 0\tag2
\end{equation}
and define
\begin{equation}
\psi(x)\overset{\mathrm{def}}=\mathrm e^{-\ell\partial^2}\phi(x)\tag3
\end{equation}
then we have
\begin{equation}
\langle 0|\psi(x)|p\rangle\neq 0\tag4
\end{equation}

The **proof** is straightforward. One just need to use $\langle0|\phi(x)|p\rangle=c\mathrm e^{ipx}$ for some non-zero constant $c$, and the trivial identity $\mathrm e^{-\ell\partial^2}\mathrm e^{ipx}=\mathrm e^{\ell p^2}\mathrm e^{ipx}$.

**Conclusion:** the non-local redefinition $(2)$ is a valid redefinition, and the $S$ matrix is invariant under it.

Comment: This is what I have as well. However there are a couple of questions: 

1. The transformation between the fields is non-invertible. Naively, if I implement the field redefinition as a change of variables in the path integral, a non-invertible transformation would be illegal as the Jacobian is 0. 

2. Boundary conditions. $\psi \rightarrow 0$ corresponds to an infinite number of boundary conditions for $\phi$. 

I'm not quite sure if these are issues or non-issues.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri note that $\phi\mapsto \mathrm e^{-\ell\partial^2}\phi$ is invertible, with inverse $\psi\mapsto \mathrm e^{+\ell\partial^2}\psi$.

Comment: But isn't it true that it will map all solutions of $\partial^{2n}\phi=0$ to zero, and these are all independent functions?

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri no, it will map all solutions of $\partial^{2n}\phi=0$ to $\phi\mapsto \phi$.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri I'm glad I could help. Cheers!