# The problem in Sredniki's textbook: How do I calculate loop corrections for $\phi\phi\to\phi\phi$ with this Lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

The problem in Sredniki's textbook 10.5 :

For a free scalar field $\psi$, the Lagrangian is 
$$\cal{L}= -\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\psi\partial_\mu\psi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\psi^2$$
Here we use the metric $\operatorname{diag}(- + + +)$

If I make $\psi=\phi+\lambda \phi^2$, then the Lagrangian is
$$\cal{L}= -\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-2\lambda\phi\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-\lambda m^2\phi^3-2\lambda^2\phi^2\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2m^2\phi^4$$

For scattering $\phi\phi \to \phi\phi $, how do I calculate the loop correction? Since the Lagrangian is now nonrenormalizable. In loop correction we need to take ghost into consideration.

Comment: Since the new and old fields commute outside the lightcone and both couple to the one-particle state, the S matrix for the new and old theories will be same.

Comment: Related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45262/scalar-field-redefinition-and-scattering-amplitude

Answer (score 1):

Take your free theory, which is the kinetic term plus the mass term, plug that into a path integral, and let the rest act as a perturbation for the generating function. Then use this generating function to calculate the 4-point correlation function.

Comment: Related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45262/scalar-field-redefinition-and-scattering-amplitude